# Migrating Pro*COBOL and Pro*C to Java: Is JDBC the way to go?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-pro-c, procobol

I am migrating [Pro*COBOL and Pro*C (code with embedded SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_SQL#Oracle_Corporation) to Java.

Am I right that I should move migrate all of the embedded SQL to JDBC calls?

Or is there a sort of "Pro*Java" way that Oracle would recommend? What is the usual best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

There was (or is?) [SQLJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLJ) for embedding SQL into Java, but I have never seen that in use anywhere.

Everything SQL-based in Java goes via JDBC.

A usual practice (not sure if a "best practice") is to abstract even further and use an ORM and some kind of persistence API.

Comment: I would not call ORB a "best practice". It might be an easy way out of the problem of Java-RDBMS communication, be it is (almost always) inefficient (my opinion is that Hybernate is horribly bad). My suggestion is stored procedures: keep all db related work inside the db. Not only it allows teh most efficient implementation (all the optimization Oracle can do with cursors), but also it allows a high level of independence. E.g. if all the data manipulation logic was developed in stored procedures then switching from Cobol and C to Java would be a trivial task (at client-db communication level)

Answer (score 0):

As there is no easy way to migrate C or worse COBOL to Java you will be doing a lot of re-writing anyway. So using JDBC with your existing SQL is probably the easiest way to go.

Another poster mentioned SQLJ which is a possibility, however I don't think it really gains you anything as you will be doing so much re-factoring anyway, however if you are happy with the whole pre-compiler thing then it will work! (At least for Oracle or DB2, support is patchy for the freebie databases).